# List View asset folders

Tags: listview, android-listview

Here is my code to list view the asset folders but how do assign in list view adapter . Here how do I use adapter

```
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.Id.listview);

        final AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        try {
            // for assets folder add empty string
                        String[] filelist = assetManager.list("");
                        // for assets/subFolderInAssets add only subfolder name
                        String[] filelistInSubfolder = assetManager.list("subFolderInAssets");
            if (filelist == null) {
                // dir does not exist or is not a directory
            } else {
                for (int i=0; i<filelist.length; i++) {
                    // Get filename of file or directory
                    String filename = filelist[i];
                }
            }

                        // if(filelistInSubfolder == null) ............  

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create  `ArrayAdapter` to fill list by this .you can use this code :

```
 listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,your String Array));
```

in this code I create a `ArrayAdapter` and fill list with that.
I hope it work for you .

Comment: How / where do define that my array list

Comment: you do't need to array list . you can fill adapter with `String Array`.you must fill the `String Array` with the file name of asset and add to my sample code . I hope this work.

Comment: String array in res/values/strings.xml . My folder name or file name in item field

Comment: string array in java like `String[] filelist`, and you can fill it with `for` loop

Comment: good luck . if this answer help you so accept for other with similar question .

Comment: Hi... can I show my html files too. When a folder name clicked it should show  the html file..any.suggestion